# getting path for files in sub_directory

Tags: python

I have written the following code to get path for files in sub_folder.

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\Users\mike\Desktop\a')
base_dir = os.getcwd()
sub_dirs = [os.path.join(base_dir, d) for d in os.listdir(base_dir)]
for i in os.listdir(sub_dirs):
    path = [os.path.join(sub_dirs), i]
```

but it does not work and I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mike\Desktop\mine1.py", line 6, in 
    for m in os.listdir(sub_dirs):
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

what is the problem?

Cheers

Comment: What do you want `os.path.join(sub_dirs)` to do?

Comment: I want to have a path for my text file                                                         like this :                                                                                                   >>> path
'C:\\Users\\mike\\Desktop\\a\x03\x01.txt'

Comment: Off-topic: Use raw strings for string literal Windows paths, or you're going to get a nasty surprise the first time a path component begins with, for example, `a`, `b`, `f` or `n` (possibly a few others). With a non-raw string, `\b` is the ASCII backspace character, not a backslash followed by `b`, and similar issues apply to the other examples. It's best to be safe and always use raw strings, e.g., in your example, `r'C:\Users\mike\Desktop\a'` (note leading `r` before open quote).

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir` needs an string or unicode as an argument. Your `sub_dirs` is a list of string.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following solve your problem?

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\Users\mike\Desktop\a')
rootDir = os.getcwd()
fileSet = set()

for dir_, _, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    for fileName in files:
        relDir = os.path.relpath(dir_, rootDir)
        relFile = os.path.join(relDir, fileName)
        fileSet.add(relFile)
```

Comment: Not really . I get this answer from python :                                                                                set(['2\\2.txt', '3\\3.txt', '1\\4.txt', '2\\3.txt', '1\\5.txt', '1\\2.txt', '1\\1.txt', '1\\3.txt', '3\\1.txt', '3\\2.txt', '2\\1.txt'])                                                                while I need  a full path like :  'C:\\Users\\mike\\Desktop\\a\x03\x01.txt'           Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hooray for recursion!

```
def recurse(files, directory):
    for item in os.listdir(directory):
        full_path = os.path.join(directory, item)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            recurse(files, full_path)
        else:
            files.append(full_path)

files = []
recurse(files, 'C:\Users\mike\Desktop\a')
```

Now your "files" list will be filled.

If you want to be able to loop over each directory's contents, you can put them in sub lists:

```
def recurse(directories, directory):
    files = []
    for item in os.listdir(directory):
        full_path = os.path.join(directory, item)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            recurse(directories, full_path)
        else:
            files.append(full_path)
    if len(files) > 0:
        directories.append((directory, files))

directories = []

recurse(directories, 'C:\Users\mike\Desktop\a')

for directory, files in directories:
    # "directory" is provided as reference (eg "C:\Users\mike\Desktop\a\a1")
    for path in files:
        # loop over each file in "directory"
        pass
```

Comment: Many thanks, your code works and gives me all files paths. But imagine if I have 3 folders in folder "a" (a1, a2, a3) and want to have the files path in 3 different loops ; (I mean , I get the path of files in a1 in the first loop. Then these values replace by paths in a2 in the second loop and finally replaced by file paths in the a3 in the third loop) . How can I change my original code to have these loops?

Comment: Updated the code to allow you to loop over the sub directories explicitly